# Update UITableViewCell labelText text issues

Tags: ios, uitableview

After a UITableView has been done, I have a async process which updates the text of 1 cell.

The update changes the text and colour e.g.

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"new text"; 
aCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

the issue I have is that these things are called but the cell seems to take seconds to actually change.

Even if I also call

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:cIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
```

The animation happens with the same delay.

Does anyone have an ideas why the cell is taking so long to update OR can anyone point me into the right direction about how to debug what is happening.  No other code is running the app is just sitting there so the UI Thread is not busy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way to update UI as you are using async process

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:cIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
});
```

**EDIT**

As per [GDC Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

> dispatch_async submits a block for asynchronous execution on a
>   dispatch queue and returns immediately.

So above block of code will get executed immediately on main queue asynchronously so as to update UI.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I thought that if I was trying to do something on the wrong thread to the UI I would get an error.  Thus I had discounted this. But this certainly fixes the issue I had.

Comment: @darbid Your issue is fixed that is nice. :)

Comment: @Bhargavi Can you explain the blocks of code for understanding what was going wrong?